# Separation of variables in derivation of soliton solutions to the KdV equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble parsing Evans PDE 2nd edition p.179:

He goes from $v'(s) = -v(s)(\sigma - 2v(s))^{1/2}$  to 
$$
s = -\int_1^{v(s)} \frac{dz}{z(\sigma - 2z)^{1/2}} + c,
$$
which looks like separation of variables, but I don't see where the limits of integration are coming from.

Comment: Please complete the reference: Title, edition, ...

Comment: Done, but the context doesn't seem to help much as my question is a single step that he doesn't clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Change dependent variable $v$ to $z$

$$dz/ds = -z(s)\sqrt{\sigma - 2z(s)}$$

$$ s = - \int \frac{dz}{{z \sqrt{\sigma - 2z}}}$$

dz/z integration involves  log z along with other functions in integration by parts, log 1 is zero, lower limit is 1, upper limit is a general point.